# Viewing totality though an unfiltered telescope

Tags: optics, vision, camera, eclipse, laboratory-safety

DISCLAIMER: This question is for informational purposes only and the ensuing discussion must not be construed as safety advice.

There seems to be a consensus among experts that partial eclipse should not be viewed or photographed without filters [3]. I get the physics argument behind that advice and follow it.
Also, there seems to be a consensus that during totality (the sun totally covered by the moon), it is fine to look at the sun (technically, the sun's corona behind the moon) with naked eyes, at least when NOT viewing through magnifying equipment like binoculars or telescopes [3].

Unfortunately, there seems to be disagreement/vagueness about whether it is safe to look at totality WITH magnifying equipment. The manual of my Meade's binoculars bluntly says "NEVER look through your binoculars at or near the Sun until the solar filters are securely installed at the front of the binoculars". [1]

Yet, there are reasonably reputable sources saying:  "During totality, it's safe to use an unfiltered telescope, pair of binoculars, or another magnifying device to view the Sun's edge and corona. If you're still looking through it the instant totality ends, even for the briefest of moments, you can blind yourself permanently". [2]

Clearly, the above two sources disagree. Neither provides much evidence for their advice. Can someone please point me to scientific evidence for either advice? More specifically, assuming I know exactly (say up to 1 second accuracy) when the totality starts and ends at my location, is there any danger in looking at totality through a telescope (or the optical viewfinder of a DSLR with telephoto lens), assuming that I start doing that 10 seconds after the totality starts and only until 10 seconds before the totality ends?
Note that I am not asking for advice. I am asking for information.

[1] : https://www.meade.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/EclipseView%E2%84%A2_10x50_Binoculars_Instruction_Manual_1-17-16.pdf

[2] : https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2017/08/14/five-things-you-must-not-do-during-totality-at-the-solar-eclipse/#2a539b5c6d89

[3] : https://eclipse2017.nasa.gov/safety

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Phys.SE is not designed to provide authoritative health & safety advices to the general public.

Comment: Hopefully, the rewording makes it clear that I am not asking for advice. I am asking for information.

Comment: @Qmechanic Did you vote as just 1/5th of the needed consensus, or invoke your diamond privilege to shove your interpretation down on everyone?

Comment: Yes, mostly because I'm concerned that this thread could harm people or be misused to validate dangerous practice. Anyway, I have asked for a second opinion in the [hbar chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39806637#39806637).

Comment: Consider also to provide a reference to the purported _consensus among experts._

Comment: @Qmechanic : Thanks for that suggestion. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @Qmechanic: There will always be people who misuse statements of others, often in totally illogical ways. Should that possibility be allowed to stifle scientific discussion? I think your judgment is mistaken.

Comment: FYI, so far there have been 2 reopen votes & 3 remain-closed votes.

Comment: @Qmechanic In my opinion, a much stronger consensus should be needed to stifle scientific discussion.